# Setting auth level in CoInitializeSecurity is not raising the authentication level

Tags: c++, winapi, rpc

I am trying to raise the auth level to `RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY` but I still get access denied failure and see the following error in event viewer:

> Application XXX is requesting with explicitly set authentication level at 2.
> The lowest activation authentication level required by DCOM is 5(RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY).
> To raise the activation authentication level, please contact the application vendor.

I am not sure why it says "level 2" when I am clearly setting it to 5 (`RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY`) in `CoInitializeSecurity()`.

Is there something else besides setting the authentication level in `CoInitializeSecurity()` that I need and is missing?

Here is my code:

```
hr = CoInitializeSecurity(NULL /*sd*/, -1, NULL, NULL,
                           RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY, 
                          RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,  NULL, 
                          EOAC_NONE, NULL);
_ASSERTE(SUCCEEDED(hr));
if(FAILED(hr))
   return hr;
```

Comment: *"I am clearly setting it to `5(RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY)` in `CoInitializeSecurity`."* - That may be clear to you. To us, it isn't. Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It works! I found out that there were other places too in the code where auth level was being changed after setting it initially with CoInitializeSecurity().